# Getting App not installed error while installing the debug APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I have created many debug APKs and tried installing them. It gets installed sometimes and sometimes shows "App installation issue".

If I go to Google Play Store Play Protect setting and turn off the "Scan device for security threats" then it gets installed smoothly.

Is there any option in Manifest or build.gradle file where I can override Play Protect setting so that the App gets installed smoothly.

The error which I receive is as follows:

[App not installed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9hsR.jpg)

How this can be corrected programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Some time debug Application is not displayed on luncher but there must be you can see it in setting > Install Application List so if you found that package in the list so first uninstall it for all user then you can install it the same issue I faced

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I have checked that the App is not there in the Installed Apps section , still Its not getting Installed. However, if I disable the Option under the Play Protect section of the Google Play Store app, it gets installed. I just need to override that option..